# How to store data into a variable with sequelize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js, backend

I’m trying to verify if the data from a form are present in the db and then send them back if true, but when I try to enclose the data in the varibile account to make the comparison does not work (account is undefined). Could someone please help me? Thank you!

```
async checkLogin(req, res, next) {
        
        let account = await Account.findAll({ where: {   
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        }})
        .catch(next);
        if(account.username == req.body.username && account.password == req.body.password) {
            res.json({
                data: { username: account.username, password: account.password} 
            })
        } else {
            console.log('error')
            console.log(req.body.username) //right
            console.log(account.username) //undefined
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to print whole `account` into console?

`sequelize` method `findAll` return not single `Account` instance, but array.
An array itself has no `username` property (that's why you get `undefined`), so firstly you have to retrieve the account out of it:

```js
const foundAccounts = await Account.findAll({...});  
const [account] = foundAccounts; // or const account = foundAccounts[0];
console.log(account.username);
```

UPD. Also you can use [findOne](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findone) instead of `findAll` to force `sequelize` to return first instance only.

```js
const account = await Account.findOne({...});
console.log(account.username);
```